# How to know count data and show in multiple table

Tags: mysql

I have some problem with my query.

This is my first table, "order":

```
id_order  id_event
------------------
    1       12    
    2       12
```

This is my second table, "event_table":

```
id_event  event_name      id_eo
--------------------------------
    12        Festival      1
    13        Music         1
```

All I want is the result like this:

```
Festival : 2 order
Music    : 0 order
```

This is what I have been done so far:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
  ORDER) AS jumorder,
  event_name
FROM
ORDER p
  INNER JOIN EVENT
    ON (p.id_event = event.id_event)
WHERE event.id_eo = '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LEFT JOIN` and `CONCAT` you can get the expected result as mentioned in the post.

```
SELECT CONCAT(E.event_name, ": ", COUNT(O.id_event), " order") Result
FROM `event_table` E
LEFT JOIN `order` O ON O.id_event = E.id_event
WHERE id_eo = '1'
GROUP BY E.event_name;
```

Result

```
Festival: 2 order
Music: 0 order
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/006c09/4

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by events:

```
select e.event_name, count(*) as jumorder 
from order p
inner join event e ON p.id_event = e.id_event
where e.id_eo = '1'
group by e.id_event, e.event_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT
      event_name AS EventName,
     COUNT(*) AS NoOfOrders
FROM event_table AS ET
LEFT JOIN order AS O
ON ET.id_order= O.id_order 
GROUP BY  event_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up the word order in backticks, and add the group by of events:

```
SELECT count(*) as jumorder,
        event_name from `order` p 
INNER JOIN event ON p.id_event=event.id_event
WHERE event.id_eo='1'
GROUP BY e.id_event, e.event_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join`:

```
select count(p.id_event) as jumorder, event_name
from event e left join
     order p 
     on p.id_event = e.id_event 
where e.id_eo = '1'
group by event_name;
```

Notes:

- For the `left join`, the `event` table needs to be first.
- `order` is a really bad name for a table, because it is a SQL reserved word.
- The `count()` needs to count a column in the matched (second) table.

Answer (score 1):

Try the query

```
SELECT CONCAT(A.event_name,' : ' ,COUNT(B.id_event),' order') Result 
FROM event_table A LEFT JOIN `order` B 
ON A.id_event = B.id_event AND A.id_eo = '1'  GROUP BY A.id_event
```

Note : Try to avoid words like 'order','like' etc. because it's already reserved for mysql..

Check [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/006c09/6)